# Map multiple values to different variables

Tags: typescript

`const x = failedCo2Quantities.map((i) => i.ITEMID);`

`const y = failedCo2Quantities.map((i) => i.PRODUCTID);`

`const z = failedCo2Quantities.map((i) => i.PLANTID);`

Is it possible to use a single map function for this?

Comment: One `.map` call returns one array, `n -> n`. You want three arrays. You could maybe do something like `const [x, y, z] = failedCo2Quantities.reduce(...)` - `.reduce` returns a single value, `n -> 1`, but that value could be an array (or object) of three arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is often used for creating a new array based on another array. Altough you can use it without getting its array result, but it is not recommended ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#when_not_to_use_map)).

```
let obj = {ITEMID:[], PRODUCTID:[], PLANTID:[]}; 
failedCo2Quantities.map(i => {
    obj.ITEMID.push(i.ITEMID);
    obj.PRODUCTID.push(i.PRODUCTID);
    obj.PLANTID.push(i.PLANTID);
    return;
});
```

Since in this case you don't want any returning value, I think `forEach` is better.

```
let obj = {ITEMID:[], PRODUCTID:[], PLANTID:[]}; 
failedCo2Quantities.forEach(i => {
    obj.ITEMID.push(i.ITEMID);
    obj.PRODUCTID.push(i.PRODUCTID);
    obj.PLANTID.push(i.PLANTID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use the reduce function.

```
failedCo2Quantities.reduce((acc, current) => {
   acc.ITEMID.push(current.ITEMID);
   acc.PRODUCTID.push(current.PRODUCTID);
   acc.PLANTID.push(current.PLANTID);
   return acc;
}, {ITEMID:[], PRODUCTID:[], PLANTID:[]})
```